# How to control the flow of vue application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a game using vue and I designed the following structure:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="status==='beforegamestart'" key="beforegamestart">
        <button v-on:click="startGame()">Start</button>
    </div>

    <div v-else-if="status==='inprocess'" key="inprocess">
        <h1>Game in process</h1>
        <button v-on:click="finishGame()">Finish</button>
    </div>

    <div v-else-if="status==='gameover'" key="gameover">
        <h2>Game over</h2>
    </div>

    <div v-else>
        <h1>Else</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'GameComponent',
    data() {
      return {
        status: 'beforegamestart'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      startGame: function() {
        this.status = "inprocess";
      },
      finishGame: function() {
        this.status = "gameover";
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I wonder what is the common way to make a game like flappy bird in vue, which has a start menu, game in process, and a finish view? Is it OK to do it in this way? I just wonder how to change different views properly.

Comment: what's your specific question? or what are the caused errors ?

Comment: No errors. I just wonder what is the normal way to switch different views of a vue application.

Comment: Normal way is using vue-router but in your case you don't need it

Comment: check out vuex.

Answer (score 1):

If I was was you, I'd do the following:

Step 1: Split the start, in-progress, and game-over screens into their own components. and import them into `App.vue`(or whatever you want) like so:

```
import Start from './Start.vue'
import Game from './Game.vue'
import GameOver from './GameOver.vue'
```

Step 2: Use a dynamic component in the template.  See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

```
<component :is="currentState"/>
```

Step 3: Have a method/computed property(or for bonus points, use vuex) that handles the current state of the game and have to components render based on that value.

```
computed: {
  currentState: function() {
    switch(status){
      case "beforeGameStart":
        return "Start";
        break;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```